# Date format not working in mysql procedure

Tags: mysql

```
{ 
delimiter &&
CREATE PROCEDURE `BPM_CLMBR_RPT_PROC` (IN customer_id INT,IN fromdate date,IN todate date)
BEGIN
-- distingushing the columns up,didntmove,down as well as group concatination
    SELECT 
    RESPONSEDATE ,
    ifnull(GROUP_CONCAT(CLIMBER, ''),0) AS 'up',
    ifnull(GROUP_CONCAT(STATIC, ''),0) AS 'didntmove',
    ifnull(GROUP_CONCAT(FALLER, ''),0) AS 'down',
    ID

FROM
    (
    -- transposing the rows to column
     SELECT 
        CASE
                WHEN report = 'STATIC' THEN count
            END AS 'STATIC',
            CASE
                WHEN report = 'CLIMBER' THEN count
            END AS 'CLIMBER',
            CASE
                WHEN REPORT = 'FALLER' THEN COUNT
            END AS 'FALLER',
            RESPONSEDATE,
            ID
    FROM
        (
        -- counting the number of records in STATIC,CLIMBER,FALLER
        SELECT 
    REPORT,RESPONSEDATE,COUNT(REPORT) count,ID
    FROM (
    -- grouping the records into STATIC,CLIMBER and FALLER
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN (FNL.PREVIOUS_SCORE BETWEEN 0 AND 6 AND FNL.CURRENT_SCORE BETWEEN 0 AND 6) THEN 'STATIC'
        WHEN (FNL.PREVIOUS_SCORE BETWEEN 7 AND 8 AND FNL.CURRENT_SCORE BETWEEN 7 AND 8) THEN 'STATIC'
        WHEN (FNL.PREVIOUS_SCORE BETWEEN 9 AND 10 AND FNL.CURRENT_SCORE BETWEEN 9 AND 10) THEN 'STATIC'
        WHEN (FNL.PREVIOUS_SCORE BETWEEN 0 AND 6 AND FNL.CURRENT_SCORE BETWEEN 7 AND 8) THEN 'CLIMBER'
        WHEN (FNL.PREVIOUS_SCORE BETWEEN 0 AND 6 AND FNL.CURRENT_SCORE BETWEEN 9 AND 10) THEN 'CLIMBER'
        WHEN (FNL.PREVIOUS_SCORE BETWEEN 7 AND 8 AND FNL.CURRENT_SCORE BETWEEN 9 AND 10) THEN 'CLIMBER'
        WHEN (FNL.PREVIOUS_SCORE BETWEEN 7 AND 8 AND FNL.CURRENT_SCORE BETWEEN 0 AND 6) THEN 'FALLER'
        WHEN (FNL.PREVIOUS_SCORE BETWEEN 9 AND 10 AND FNL.CURRENT_SCORE BETWEEN 0 AND 6) THEN 'FALLER'
        WHEN (FNL.PREVIOUS_SCORE BETWEEN 9 AND 10 AND FNL.CURRENT_SCORE BETWEEN 7 AND 8) THEN 'FALLER'
    END AS 'REPORT', 
    FNL.RESPONSEDATE,
    ID
FROM (
SELECT 
-- group concatination using space but only one client responses is expected
    CLIENTID,
    CLIENTNAME,
    GROUP_CONCAT(TEMP.CURRENT_SCORE, '') AS 'CURRENT_SCORE',
    GROUP_CONCAT(TEMP.PREVIOUS_SCORE, '') AS 'PREVIOUS_SCORE',
    GROUP_CONCAT(TEMP.COMMENT,'') AS 'COMMENT',
    max(id) ID,
    max(responsedate) RESPONSEDATE
FROM
    (
    -- Top two npsscores are taken into account and only 1st comment is taken
    SELECT 
        CLIENTID,id,CLIENTNAME,
            CASE
                WHEN RANK = 1 THEN npsscore
            END AS 'CURRENT_SCORE',
            CASE
                WHEN RANK = 2 THEN npsscore
            END AS 'PREVIOUS_SCORE',
            CASE 
                WHEN RANK=1 THEN COMMENT
            END AS 'COMMENT',
             RESPONSEDATE
    FROM
        (
        -- NPS_CLIENT_STATUS is calculated and only the 1st and 2nd rank holders are selected
SELECT 
    CLMBR_RPT.*,CASE
                WHEN CLMBR_RPT.NPSSCORE BETWEEN 0 AND 6 THEN 'DETRACTOR'
                WHEN CLMBR_RPT.NPSSCORE BETWEEN 7 AND 8 THEN 'PASSIVE'
                ELSE 'PROMOTER'
        END 'NPS_CLIENT_STATUS'
FROM
    (
    -- rank funtion is in corporated rownum() in Oracle 
    SELECT 
        a.*,
            (CASE a.CLIENTID
                WHEN @curType THEN @curRow:=@curRow + 1
                ELSE @curRow:=1 AND @curType:=a.CLIENTID
            END) AS rank
    FROM
        (SELECT 
    NSR.*
FROM
    nps_summary_report NSR
        INNER JOIN
        -- innerjoin is done to get all the client id for a given date span which jas multiple records in the nps_summary_report table
        -- joined with nps_summary_report table will eliminate all the records in the nps_summary_report table which is not having 
        -- customerid , multiple responses and date
        -- this is  the innermost query and will execute first and eliminate all the unwanted records 
    (SELECT 
        CLIENTID
    FROM
        nps_summary_report
    WHERE CUSTOMERID=customer_id -- TO BE PROVIDED
      -- AND RESPONSEDATE  between  STR_TO_DATE(fromdate, '%m/%d/%Y') AND  STR_TO_DATE(todate, '%m/%d/%Y')   -- TO BE PROVIDED
       AND RESPONSEDATE  >  fromdate and RESPONSEDATE< todate   -- TO BE PROVIDED
     --  AND RESPONSEDATE BETWEEN  date_format(STR_TO_DATE(@fromdate, '%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d') AND  date_format(STR_TO_DATE(@todate, '%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d') 
      -- AND RESPONSEDATE BETWEEN  date_format(@fromdate,'%Y-%m-%d') AND  date_format(@todate,'%Y-%m-%d') 
    GROUP BY CLIENTID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) CLNT_ID ON CLNT_ID.CLIENTID = NSR.CLIENTID ) a, -- REMOVING ALL THE CLIENT WHICH HAVE 1 FEEDBACK 
    (SELECT @curRow:=0, @curType:='') r
    WHERE CUSTOMERID=customer_id -- RETREIVE ALL DATA FOR BOOKMYSHOW ONLY
    ORDER BY CLIENTID , RESPONSEDATE ) CLMBR_RPT
WHERE
    CLMBR_RPT.RANK BETWEEN 0 AND 2)STG_BMS_CLIMBER_RPT
    GROUP BY CLIENTID , CASE
        WHEN RANK = 1 THEN npsscore
    END , CASE
        WHEN RANK = 2 THEN npsscore
    END,CASE 
        WHEN RANK=1 THEN COMMENT
    END
    ) TEMP
GROUP BY CLIENTID) FNL ) TBL
GROUP BY RESPONSEDATE,REPORT)stg_temp) TEMP
GROUP BY RESPONSEDATE
order by RESPONSEDATE desc;
END
&&
delimiter ; }
```

I am calling the stored procedure by

```
{ call BPM_CLMBR_RPT_PROC(6,str_to_date('2015-10-01','%Y-%m-%d'),str_to_date('2015-12-31','%Y-%m-%d')); }
```

The query is returning all the records irrespective of the date constraints .But when a hard coded value is passed inside the code like

```
{
RESPONSEDATE BETWEEN  date_format(STR_TO_DATE('11/1/2015', '%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d') AND  date_format(STR_TO_DATE('12/13/2015', '%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d')
}
```

then the expected result is comming.

Comment: You can't pass `str_to_date` in a call function. Why don't you change the parameter type to `varchar` and then invoke `str_to_date` (to convert to `date`) internally in the procedure?

Comment: Thanks @SameerMirji 
I have tried with 
`RESPONSEDATE  between  STR_TO_DATE(fromdate, '%m/%d/%Y') AND  STR_TO_DATE(todate, '%m/%d/%Y') ` 

and calling it with 

`call BPM_CLMBR_RPT_PROC(6,'10/1/2015','12/13/2015');`

But it didn't work

Comment: Use `str_to_date` for `RESPONSEDATE` also. Like this: `STR_TO_DATE(RESPONSEDATE, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(fromdate, '%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(todate, '%m/%d/%Y')`